# Origin of Electromagnetic Interactions between Molecules

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, molecules

What is the origin of electromagnetic interaction between molecules? Anyway, it should have some relation with atoms. Also, These electromagnetic interactions are playing a major role in different properties of matter including the transition between solid-liquid-gas. Hence, what would be the **source** of these interactions..?

If these interactions originate from atoms, then some other questions come into **focus**:

- Are they related to the transition of electrons between various energy levels and emission of photons from an atom..?
- Are they related to [cohesive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28chemistry%29) forces between molecules in solids & liquids?

Comment: note, that not all of the interactions (especially repelling) between molecules are electromagnetic in nature.

Comment: @Yrogig: Could you please provide a link for deeper study..?

Comment: I meant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_repulsion they are the forces that account for repelling between molecules at small distances. The book "Intermolecular and surface forces" by Israelachvili (Chapter 7) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mainly an [electrostatic interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force) through a dipole-dipole interaction. However, the dipole moment can be permanent or induced. Depending on its nature the force has a different name:

- force between two permanent dipoles ([Keesom force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force#Dipole.E2.80.93dipole_interactions))
- force between a permanent dipole and a corresponding induced dipole ([Debye force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force#Debye_.28induced_dipole.29_force))
- force between two instantaneously induced dipoles ([London dispersion force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force#London_dispersion_force))

You can also refer [Vanderwaals Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force)

An atom or molecule is usually globaly neutral: ie there is exactly the same number of positive and negative charges. However the center of charge (barycenter of the qi) for the positive and negative charges does not always coincide. This gives rise to an electrostatic dipole that can interact with an external electric field. To answer to your first bullet, the electrostaic dipole is not linked to electrons changing orbital.
The cohesive forces in solids have two different origin: orbital coupling (not of electromagnetic nature) or ionic bonds in ionic crystals (Na+, Cl-) for instance. In the latter the cohesion of the crystal is due to electrostaic interaction (not dipolar). For the liquids, the electrostatic forces are responsible for the observed properties. Polar solutions are made of molecules with a dipolar moment and are able to dissolve ionic crystals.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "electromagnetic interaction between molecules" is mostly due to [Electrostatic force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force) in the form of [dipole-dipole forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole-dipole_interaction#Dipole-dipole_interactions) and so on.

Comment: This is not completely correct-- London forces are electrostatic, but Casimir forces are electrodynamic, and the transition is important at distances which are not infinite, but comparable to the wavelength of the atomic transitions.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: I respectfully disagree, as I said "mostly due", and, as far as I know, Casimir forces are relatively very small, as evidenced by the fact that they were experimentally discovered decades after they were predicted. Therefore, I believe my answer is "completely correct", although it was not intended to be "complete".

Comment: Casimir forces are not so small, they are continuously linked to electrostatic London forces as the separation gets small. The measurements are only difficult for macroscopic objects.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: So could you give a reference (earlier than, say, 1972 - remember, Casimir forces were discovered theoretically around 1948) to experimental evidence of Casimir forces for microscopic objects? Or otherwise explain in what sense Casimir forces are not so small? Or do you mean that electrostatic forces are in fact electrodynamic as they are photon-mediated? So far I just don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that the Van-Der-Waals force, the coefficients "a" and "b" in the thermodynamic equation of state calculated by Van-Der-Waals, can be estimated from a ${1\over r^7}$ potential, not a ${1\over r^6}$ potential, with a cross over at some hundreds of atomic radii. The ${1\over r^6}$ force is electrostatic, and calculated by London from second order perturbation theory. I believe the discrepancy with experiment was noted by Casimir. The ${1\over r^7}$ force was calculated electrodynamically by Casimir, before Bohr suggested using vacuum energy, and the long-range part was known to be r^7.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: I still could not understand you until I looked at http://pharmahub.org/resources/372/download/InterparticleForces-versus-BulkBehavior.pdf , Eq. (27). It turns out that Casimir force only contributes significantly to Van der Waals force when the distance is very large, say, 0.1 micron, when Van der Waals force itself is very small. Therefore, it is correct that molecular forces are mostly electrostatic and that Casimir force is relatively very small.

Comment: You shouldn't say "contributes significantly", the Van-Der-Waals force _is_ the Casimir force! They are two names for the same thing. The near-field London force is called London force. The crossover radius is the wavelength of light emitted by the molecules, it is roughly visible wavelengths, so a tenth of a micron. I agree it's smaller than the London forces, I am not sure it is always negligible, because it is an attenuation of the force, so it cuts off long range electrostatic contributions.

Comment: If you use such definitions that "the Van-Der-Waals force is the Casimir force", you should not have said that "London forces are electrostatic, but Casimir forces are electrodynamic" - I had all the reasons to believe that by "the Casimir force" you meant the correction to the electrostatic force. Otherwise your phrase "Casimir forces are not so small" makes no sense within this discussion - it turns out that, according to your definition, Casimir force contains electrostatic force as well, so if "Casimir forces are not so small", this cannot disprove my "mostly due".

Comment: It's not my definition, but I don't want to quibble over word choice. Casimir forces are the forces calculated by Casimir, which are the the retarded version of London force.

Comment: That means that you started this discussion with a misleading statement about Casimir forces being electrodynamic, whereas, under the definition you use, they include a significant electrostatic part and thus cannot be regarded as an argument against my wording "mostly due". I stand by that wording.

Comment: It's not misleading--- Casimir forces are not electrostatic, they are electrodynamic, because they are retarded. You don't get them from electrostatic interaction, you get dipole-dipole forces from second order perturbation theory. I am using standard terminology, but I don't want to quibble over words. I agree that macroscopic forces are mostly electrostatic, the Casmir force is the only exception. It's not the dominant near-field force, and so I can live with your answer as it is, although you could easily make it complete by mentioning Casimir forces.